# Is there a combination of curl flags that logs a clean request/response headers and body data?

Tags: curl

curl has a lot of flags. Many answers on stack exchange websites recommend:

```
--verbose but it displays a lot of network related data and certificates and handshakes, and it does not show the request body
--header it only shows headers, and only response headers
--trace-ascii this shows the body, but not in a human-readable format
-i only shows the response headers and body, but it's clean
-D only shows the response headers
...
```

What I want is a simple log of request/response headers and bodies.

My requests are not `multipart/form-data`. My requests are either sending and receiving simple JSON data, or key-value pairs.

Basically what I need is this log:

```
curl api.example.com -d '{"name":"somboeyd"}'

***************

request headers
one empty line
request body

***************

response headers
one empty line
response body
```

Can I mix flags to create this? If not, is there a command line utility to do the job of curl but with this clean log?

Comment: You can use `-D filename` to dump headers to that file, so `curl -D headers.txt -d 'data' 'https://example.com/path' > output.txt` might work; `cat`ting the two files should be straightforward enough.

Comment: @DopeGhoti, `-D` only dumps **response** headers, not request headers. That's my problem. Any flag just does one part of the overall problem and it seems that when we combine flags, the log becomes dirty.

Comment: You could filter out the lines starting with `*` from `curl --verbose` with a `grep -v` but you might have to get creative to not _also_ block lines of the _body_ that happen to also start with an asterisk.

Comment: @DopeGhoti, as I've mentioned in the question, `--verbose` does not log the request body.

Answer (score 0):

I found [HTTPie](https://httpie.io/) and it's perfect.

This is the command I use:

```
http --follow --verbose POST https://api.example.com Content-Type:application/json key1=value1 key2=value2
```

And it has fantastic output. Curl belongs to the past.